# checkbox state propagating incorrectly from model to UI

Tags: knockout.js, checkbox

Funny things happening in my UI which using knockout bindings.

Ui is defined as follows:

```
<ul id="items" data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li>        
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.selectedItems, value: $data, click: $root.itemsChanged"/>
        <label data-bind="text: $data"></label>
    </li>
</ul>

<div data-bind="foreach: selected">
    <p data-bind="text:$data"></p>
</div>
```

Js which is included in the head portion goes like:

```
function ViewModel(items) {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.itemsChanged = function () {
        self.selected.removeAll();
        self.selectedItems().forEach(function (e) {
            self.selected.push(e);
        });
    };
    self.selected = ko.observableArray([]);
}

var model = new ViewModel(['Read paper', 'Clear room', 'Cook food', 'Buy rice']);
window.onload = function () {
    ko.applyBindings(model);
};
```

**What I expect:** When I check the first checkbox, it should show the checked state, and the div should get correctly populated with the checked item.

**What I observe:** When I check the first checkbox, it doesn't get checked. But the div below populates correctly. Check another checkbox, the first checkbox clicked gets checked; the one that is clicked doesn't get checked. The div however reflects the item.

Am I doing something wrong?

Fiddle for use: http://jsfiddle.net/deostroll/BNfKF/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using the `checked` binding together with the `click` binding you need to return `true` from your click handler [to trigger the browsers default behavior](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note_3_allowing_the_default_click_action) in order to your checkboxes checked correctly:

```
self.itemsChanged = function () {
    self.selected.removeAll();
    self.selectedItems().forEach(function (e) {
        self.selected.push(e);
    });
    return true;
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ETWrV/).

But your code in the `itemsChanged` is not really needed because KO will track the selected items in the `selectedItems` array so there is no need to copy it. You use can use it directly:

```
<ul id="items" data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li>        
        <input type="checkbox" 
             data-bind="checked: $root.selectedItems, value: $data"/>
        <label data-bind="text: $data"></label>
    </li>
</ul>

<div data-bind="foreach: selectedItems">
    <p data-bind="text:$data"></p>
</div>
```

And in your ViewModel you don't need the `itemsChanged` function:

```
function ViewModel(items){
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray([]);       
    self.selected = ko.observableArray([]);
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jkf4K/).